# Keynote: change the font of an equation

Tags: font, keynote, latex

I'm using the built-in equation tool in Keynote. Is there a way to change the font used by default in Keynote?

Also, I see that when I try to use text in the equation via `\text{}` the font is in bold mode. How can I change that?

Note that a relevant Keynote question has been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417728/keynote-long-text-with-latex-symbols).

As an example for the font change see this picture
[image]

As an example for the bold text see the picture which was generated by `\Gamma \text{ is fixed}`

[image]

Note that this question is not a duplicate of [this one](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315421/change-equation-font-in-pages). All of the options mentioned in the linked question are such that simply add a characteristic to the font (italics, bold, roman etc.) but they do not change the font.

Comment: @grg this does not solve the issue. It does not tell you how to change the font to some other font. It only gives you text modes inside an equation. Note that the fonts are different. e.g. the f is not the same f using the equation generator and LatexIT.

Comment: What do you mean by "change in between the font, and not the font itself"?

Comment: I mean that the fonts, in the picture above are not the same. you can see it clearly in the small x written there. I don't see how the options mentioned in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315421/change-equation-font-in-pages give a way to transform the x on the left to the x on the right.

Comment: I would say that the "f" doesn't look the same either. But basically you are looking for way to have the "f" in one font, and the "x" in another?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining myself correctly. I am looking for a way to change the entire font. I want also the f to look like the original CMU serif font as seen on the right picture. (I didn't mention the f since I thought most people wouldn't see the difference).

Comment: So why does the answer in the other question not help you here? Seems to describe a way to change the font

Comment: @nohillside I do not understand. For example `\mathit` makes the font italic, but it doesn't change it really. All of the options mentioned in the linked question are such that simply add a characteristic to the font (italics, bold, roman etc.) but they do not change the font. Could you explain how can I change the font in the left picture of my original question to the one in the right picture?

Comment: I've edited your question to reflect what you explained in the comments. Feel free to amend if I got it wrong.

Comment: @nohillside. thanks! that is a perfect way to explain it.

Comment: @nohillside Isn't this question a duplicate of the one I asked? Obviously no satisfactory answer was given to that question, but it seems like this question and the other question are *asking* the same exact thing.

Comment: @SkeletonBow I just read both questions again, you are right, they basically are the same. And we usually close as duplicate in such cases, don't know what I was thinking two years ago :-) Will keep an eye on this one once the bounty expires.

Comment: Has there been a confusion in this comment section? Font _technically_  means: is the text bold, italic, etc., but lots of people (including myself often) use it instead to mean typeface. Typeface means: the design of the letters.

Comment: @theonlygusti The question here asks "change the font of an equation", the linked question asked "Is there any way to change the font used".

Comment: @nohillside I am just pointing out that it's not obvious what either OP wants unless there are clues as to whether they mean font or typeface. Obviously, the other question has answers explaining how to change the font using blahtex macros. Maybe that's not helpful to this OP because they want to change the typeface? The second answer on the other question seems to talk about typeface though, but it's true `\text{}` seems to be bolded. Anyway, there just seems to have been a lot of confusion, and that confusion may be able to be resolved by using technical vocabulary.

Comment: @theonlygusti The question here says that the OP doesn't think the existing *answers* answer their question (which is mostly correct but this also applies to the original question). The way to go in such cases is to raise a bounty on the original question, inviting additional answers. This will keep things together and make it easier to find them. With the bounty set on this question here closing is currently not an option.

Answer (score 1):

There’s no way to change the default font output of the standard LaTeX editor in Keynote.

There might be a way through changing the editor itself, though of course strictly speaking it wouldn’t be Keynote anymore, more of a customized variant.

So practically, no.

Old Answer (for temporary changes):

Yes

\mathfrak{x=2y} clearly changes the font in Keynote, and Pages as mentioned in the question you linked.

Comment: The question is not asking about `\mathfrak` or `\mathbf` etc., it's asking about changing the font family, e.g. to Computer Modern instead of whatever the default font is.

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out, the Latex editor in Keynote does not support changing the default font, I’ll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use math spacing when inserting text, such as `\Gamma \;{is} \:{fixed} \:{for} \;{f(x)}`, with the result as in picture below:

[image]

Comment: Take care of environment - here was with font size 34, may look bold.

Comment: I do not understand. What you suggest does not help in fixing the font to match CMU fonts.