# What font does keynote (iWork) equation editor use?

Tags: macos, keynote

I want to match regular text with the equations, but as far as I can tell, there's no way to figure out what font is being used for LaTeX and MathML style markdown.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202501

What font does the Keynote/Pages equation editor use by default?

Comment: Is the answer here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315421/change-equation-font-in-pages

Comment: @benwiggy No. That page is like tons of others—how to *change* the font, not about the default font itself.

Comment: It looks quite close to Times/Times New Roman. I can get text to match with it if I'm very fiddly with the font size.

Comment: Doesn't the answer list all the fonts that the Latex framework uses?

Comment: Are you using a specific template in a specific version of Keynote for macOS? It seems this is not trivial due to all the presets for headings, text styles and sizes / weights. Even trying to parse a “trivial” equation produces 60 thousand characters in a one line export to PDF.

Comment: @bmike My experience is that the equations are always rendered with the same font, regardless of the theme used. I tried with a few just now.

Comment: Odd, I got three different sizes on three different slide types but I authored on iPad since that’s handy for me